# Proving Similarity and Finding x of a Cone

Tags: geometry

Following the image below, I need to find x. I know that there are two cones and I need to prove similarity. I can prove similarity on 2D objects, but not 3D. Would I use volume, or something else? However, I know that once similarity is proven I can use cross multiplication to find x, still confused on what values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/toAuM.jpg

Comment: Take a cross section passing through the axis of the cone, then in this cross section everything will be 2D, and you will have two triangles instead of cones.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance